# Loop skipping over input in golang

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to check if an input is blank and ask for input again using a for loop, but the program is just repeatedly going over the loop without stopping to wait for input and outputting the print statement within it 100 times, what am I doing wrong?

```
var input string

    for len(input) == 0 {

        fmt.Println("What would you like to write in the journal?")

        input = usr.GetInput()

    }
```

GetInput uses bufio.NewScanner and returns scanner.Text, but even when I try Scanln, the error still occurs.

Edit:

As requested here is GetInput

```
func GetInput() string {

    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

    return scanner.Text()

}
```

Comment: `len(input) <= 1`  cause pressing return means `\n` special char which is 1 symbol You can check it by doing `println(len(input))`

Comment: If GetInput calls bufio.NewScanner on every call, then GetInput slurps up some amount of input, returns the first line and discards the rest.  Show the code for GetInput.

Comment: or add: `input = strings.TrimSpace(input)` after input

Comment: @CeriseLimón I don't think GetInput is the problem, I had initially used Scanln and it did the same thing with that, but if you still think it's necessary I can add it.

Comment: @num8er I'm pressing enter or anything when the code runs, it just instantly prints the statement repeatedly as soon as the code runs.

Comment: @crispy need more code, we cannot predict what is GetInput

Comment: @crispy use `ReadString` instead or do `scanner.Scan()` before `scanner.Text()` https://thedeveloperblog.com/bufio

Comment: That's not how you use a `bufio.Scanner`. Take a look at the [example in the documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/bufio#example-Scanner-Lines)

Comment: @JimB Thanks for this suggestion, after trying it again with fmt.Scanln() I realized I had omitted the reference asterisk to try to understand better why I needed to pass a reference instead of just the variable itself, after adding the asterisk the program works perfectly, do you know why I need that btw? Marking the question as answered, thanks again.

Comment: @crispy The [fmt package documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/fmt#hdr-Scanning) says that the arguments to the scan functions must be *either pointers to basic types or implementations of the Scanner interface*.  Use the address operator `&` to get a pointer.  The Scanln function returns an error describing the problem. Always check input errors.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the program to work by trying it again with fmt.Scanln(), and this time including a pointer to the variable with an asterisk instead of just putting the variable in Scanln.